# Check android:allowBackup value programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-security, android-backup-service

As I have studied about the security issues in Android, one good practice is to check if the `allowBackup` and `backupAgent` has been set in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

How to check `android:allowBackup` value of an app programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
      if ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP) != 0) {
         // enabled
      } else {
         // disabled
      }
```

Comment: (packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP) != 0 --  this line throws NameNotFound exception. still can't figure out why. Are sure about the '&' part ?

Comment: I've taken that `if` from platform's sources and have tested with both enabled and disabled state, works as expected. Which component causes `NameNotFoundException`?

Comment: NameNotFoundException means the app referred to by package name is not installed. Check package name given to getPackageInfo().

Comment: This is not the most appropriate solution as one can get ApplicationInfo with getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo() without requiring an extra step getting PackageInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Check out FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP and the other related flags in [ApplicationInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it using the below code:

```
if ((getApplication().getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_ALLOW_BACKUP) != 0) {
    Log.e("data", "enabled"); // enabled
} else {
    Log.e("data", "disabled"); // disabled
}
```